Power BI / MDX: re-sort hierarchy for custom report design (change order)
I have a problem with an accounts hierarchy in Power Bi. I built the hierarchy according to the underlying metadata structure, flattened it, sorted by levels and so on. It´s working as intended, yet I do have a problem with the structure of the hierarchy compared to the report I want to build.
The structure of the hierarchy looks as below:

Profit after tax

Tax

Profit before tax

Income

xyz


Expense

xyz







I want to show the report to some degree "the other way around":

Income

Expense

Profit before tax

Tax

Profit after tax


One Idea I had was to exclude profit before and after tax and create measure for those two. Else I wondered if it would be possible to have a hierarchy opening up from the bottom to the top?
Does anyone have a solution for this (MDX functions or smart ideas)? Any input is highly appreciated, thanks so much.

Can you share some data ?also I understand from your question that your datasource is an SSAS cube ?
